# Prove identity about divergence of vector fields

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f,g$ be scalar smooth functions and $\Phi:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ be a smooth vector field. How do I prove that the following identity holds?
$$div\Bigg(g(x) \nabla h(f) - h(f) \nabla g(x) - g(x) h(f) \Phi \Bigg)= g(x)h''(f) |\nabla f|^2 - h(f)(\Delta g + \Phi \cdot \nabla g) + g h'(f) (\Delta f - \Phi \cdot \nabla f)$$

I tried to do the computations many times over, but I'm missing some pieces. The one $- h(f)(\Delta g + \Phi \cdot \nabla g)$ is the only I get consistently from my computations.

Comment: What is $h$ here?

Comment: $div(g(x)h(f)\vec{F})=\partial_i(g(x)h(f)F_i)=(\partial_i{g(x)})h(f){F_i}+g(x)(\partial_i{f})(\frac{d}{df}h(f)){F_i}+g(x)h(f)\partial_i{F_i}=(\nabla{g(x)}\vec{F})h(f)+g(x)(\frac{d}{df}h(f))(\nabla{f}\vec{F})+g(x)(div\vec{F})h(f)$

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the dumb indexes technique (Einstein's summation technique, if I'm not mistaken): $div\vec{a}=\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}a_i (or =\partial_i{a_i}), \Delta{g}=\partial_i\partial_ig$ (summation over repeated indices is implied), etc.

For instance, $div(\nabla{h(f)})=\partial_i\partial_i{h(f)}=\partial_i((\frac{d}{df}h)\partial_i{f})=(\frac{d^2}{df^2}h)\partial_i{f}\partial_i{f}+(\frac{d}{df}h)\partial_i\partial_i{f}=(\frac{d^2}{df^2}h)|\nabla{f}|^2+(\frac{d}{df}h)\Delta{f}$

$div(g(x)\vec{F})=\partial_i(g(x)F_i)=\partial_i{g(x)}F_i+g(x)\partial_iF_i=\nabla{g(x)}\vec{F}+g(x)div\vec{F}$, and so on.

Using this technique you can easily do any transformations of any complexity in a space of any dimension, not necessarily $R^2$.

Hopefully, this will help.